# How to refactore an angularjs filter to directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a complex filter, and would like to refactor it to a directive.

Lets take a simple example:

```
app.filter('tolower', function() {
    return function(input) {
        return input.toLowerCase(); //simple example
    }
});

<div ng-bind-html="'TEST' | tolower"></div>
```

How could I refactor this so that I can use a directive as follows:

```
<div tolower="TEST"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
app.directive('tolower', function(tolowerFilter) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.html(tolowerFilter(attrs.tolower));
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a scope with the 'tolower' to your directive like this so that you can use tolower as an attribute:

```
.directive('MyDirective', function(config) {
...
scope: {
      tolower: '='
   },
...
});
```

Then, in your controller handler :

```
function MyDirectiveController($filter) {
var vm = this;
...
vm.loweredValue = $filter('tolower')(vm.tolower);
...
}
```

Finally, you can use the loweredValue by injecting it in the element's DOM.